# how avoid figcaption wrapping with media query

Tags: css

i'm working now with media query and once i reach the breakpoint of 768px the text goes

all below the images, not following them.

I would like the text to follow the images and to be under each one once it reach the 768px breakpoint.

any suggestion to avoid this problem?

thanks.

[image]

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  
  
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    margin-top: 200px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center; 
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    /* navbar */

    * {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.nav-links, .search{
    display: none;
}


.logo {
  height: 64px;
  width: 126px;
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 1px;

}

/* contenuto1 */

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 100px;
    grid-gap: 150px;
  }
```

```
<div class="titolo-grid">
    <h2>In evidenza</h2>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid">
      <img src="1w.webp" class="img"/>
      <img src="2w.webp" class="img"/>
      <img src="3w.webp" class="img"/>
      <figcaption class="caption">I riflessi fluidi dell'autunno</figcaption>
      <figcaption class="caption">Maglieria</figcaption>
      <figcaption class="caption">Scarpe Made In Italy</figcaption>
     
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you not have your image and the caption wrapped into a `figure` element to begin with? The way you currently have this, the captions do not even have any relation to any specific image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do not use a grid unless you know how to manipulate it. I suggest you use `display flex` because it's easier to manipulate and more simple.

and to put text under each image, you must understand the importance of HTML structure for that. so put each image with its text in a container, then style them according to that.

I used display flex here:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    
    
  }
  
  .grid {
      display: flex;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); */
      margin-top: 200px;
      grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center; 
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .container  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
      /* navbar */
  
      * {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  
  .nav-links, .search{
      display: none;
  }
  
  
  .logo {
    height: 64px;
    width: 126px;
    filter: invert(100%);
    padding: 1px;
  
  }

  .grid {
  
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 200px;    
}
  
  /* contenuto1 */
  
  /* .grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-top: 100px;
      grid-gap: 150px;
    } */
}
```

```html
 
  <div class="titolo-grid">
    <h2>In evidenza</h2>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="img1 container" >
        <img src="1w.webp" class="img"/>
        <figcaption class="caption">I riflessi fluidi dell'autunno</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div class="img2 container" >
        <img src="2w.webp" class="img"/>
        <figcaption class="caption">Maglieria</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div class="img3 container" >
        <img src="3w.webp" class="img"/>
        <figcaption class="caption">Scarpe Made In Italy</figcaption>
      </div>
      
     
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I actually tried to just put them in a container and it worked but the images size wasn't stable, so I added some adjustments to the code as well to make sure all images have equal size.

Comment: because I set `img min-width: 200px;` I think you resize the screen smaller than any phone that we have these days. there is no phone lower than 200px width. but you can remove it or change it if you want.

Comment: seriously!, you removed the upvote because I'm trying to help you for free? WOW!

Answer (score 0):

Put `<img>` and `<figcaption>` inside `<figure>`:

```
<figure>
   <img src="1w.webp" class="img"/>
   <figcaption class="caption">I riflessi fluidi dell'autunno</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
   <img src="2w.webp" class="img"/>
   <figcaption class="caption">Maglieria</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:row;
  margin-top: 100px;
  }
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;  
}

 .grid{
   width:31%;
   margin:1%;
  }

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    /* navbar */

    * {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.nav-links, .search{
    display: none;
}


.logo {
  height: 64px;
  width: 126px;
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 1px;

}
  .grid{
    width:100%;
  }
  .caption{
    margin:10px auto 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="titolo-grid">
    <h2>In evidenza</h2>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid">
      <img src="1w.webp" class="img"/>
      <figcaption class="caption">I riflessi fluidi dell'autunno</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <img src="2w.webp" class="img"/>
      <figcaption class="caption">Maglieria</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <img src="3w.webp" class="img"/>
      <figcaption class="caption">Scarpe Made In Italy</figcaption>
     
    </div>
    </div>
```

you need to put `img` and `figcaption` inside the `gri`d element and use `Flex` instead of `Grid` some codes:

Comment: @Drean: please mark it as solved if it helped ;)

Comment: Actually there shouldn't be any problem. You might zoomed in the page or something, but I blieve it works fine on Iphone :)